# Why Lead.Name is null

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have assigned values to a Lead record.  I looked at the same record via regular UI Listview and the field Name is ok (concatenation of FirstName and LastName).  However the System.debug shows "null".  Why this discrepancy?

```
Lead myLead = new Lead();
myLead.Company = 'Tesla Motors';
myLead.LastName = 'Musk';
myLead.FirstName = 'TechnoKing';

System.debug('Here is the new Lead: ' + myLead.Company + ' and Lead Name: ' + myLead.Name );
```

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is special field calculated at runtime when you view a saved record. You'd need to insert it and query the value. 2 reasons:

1. For you it might be natural to go "FirstName LastName" but there are cultures that prefer "LastName FirstName". Chinese/Japanese/Korean (often abbreviated to CJK). And bit closer to home - Hungarian for example, I kid you not. See the list at https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5. So `Lead.Name`, `Contact.Name`, `User.Name` is special, it's not a real field, it depends who's looking.
2. "Name" is a bigger concept than just "John Doe". It can include Salutation (Mr, Ms etc), Middle name (if you enabled that in setup, even suffixes. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332623&type=1&mode=1 So it's 1 data source to keep in mind when composing at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  From what I can tell, the first 4 lines do the job of inserting the record - as can be viewed in the Listview of Leads.  However line 6, with system.debug, it shows NULL.

Comment: 1. Code you posted creates a Lead in memory but nothing will happen without `insert myLead;` or similar. Maybe you didn't copy that line. 2. After successful insert all you get back is the record's Id being populated. If you want to see Name, formula fields, fields set by workflow, triggers etc "side effects" not explicitly set by your code - you need to `Lead myNewLead = [SELECT Name FROM Lead WHERE Id = :myLead.Id];` There's no magical in-memory replacement